# Node Crash on AWS CentOS 7 when posting json

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a very simple app that has been working with for over year and on different flavors of Linux and windows.  The only difference is I've spun a box on AWS that is using **CentOS version 7.7.1908** with **Mongo 4.2.5** and **Node 12.16.0**.  I'm currently running the exact same code on Windows 10 and on CentOS 8.  I've run it on Ubuntu as well.  No issues.

On the AWS box I can launch Mongo (Read & Write) and execute a node file. So I know the services work.

BUT, from Postman when I hit an endpoint with the objective to write JSON to the db.  It fails immediately when user_find is executed.  I've tracked it down to this code below.

**Found where it fails:  I've removed all my code just want to write to console to see if it even reaches that far.**

**contoller.users.js**

```
const User      = require('../models/user');
const mongoose  = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt    = require('bcrypt'); 

console.log('Controller Read');   //This displays in the console when the app is launched. It also proves the routing is correct as well.
exports.user_find = (req, res, next) => {
        console.log('User Find Activated');   //When I try to send data the app fails and never gets this message.
    }
```

**I was thinking maybe my modules version are fighting.  I downgraded some but it didn't matter.
This is what I currently have.**

```
"dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^4.0.1",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "mongoose": "^5.9.7",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.3"
    }
```

**Here is my app code.

```
const express    = require('express');
const app        = express();
const morgan     = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose   = require('mongoose');

// Application Routes
    const customerRoutes  = require('./api/routes/customers');
    const orderRoutes     = require('./api/routes/orders');
    const userRoutes      = require('./api/routes/users');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017', { dbName: 'myDB', useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }).
    then(() => console.log('db Connected')).
    catch(err => console.log('Caught', err.stack));

//For Dev purposes
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

//This piece of code deals with CORS errors
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization');
        if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT','POST','PATCH','DELETE');
            return res.status(200).json({});
        }
        next();
    });

//Routes to handle requests
    app.use('/customers', customerRoutes);
    app.use('/orders', orderRoutes);
    app.use('/users', userRoutes);

    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        const error = new Error( 'App Crash' );
        error.status = 404;
        next(error);
    });

    app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
        res.status(error.status || 500);
        res.json({error: {message: error.message}
        });
    });


module.exports = app;
```

> In mongod.conf  I've also commented out the BindIP.  It's open to
>   anything.  When the app launches I get a db connected so I know it
>   works.

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens when your programming all night, I get all bent out of shape a post looking for help.  Have a nap...and voila!   The problem was that I had a type O in the URL in postman.   Nothing wrong with the code.